# How to access various parts of a link with XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm fairly new to XPath and wanted to see how granular you can get when accessing various HTML components.

I'm currently using the this xpath

```
//*[@id=\"resultsDiv\"]/p[1]/a
```

to access the HTML (abbreviated) below:

```
<p style="margin:0;border-width:0px;"><a href="./t_Person.aspx?PersonID=140476">Bill%20Jones</a></p>
```

The XPath returns this: `<a href="./t_Person.aspx?PersonID=140476">Bill%20Jones</a>`

But what I'm trying to get is simply the PersonID = 140476.

**Question**: Is it possible to write an XPath that results in `140476`, or do I need to take what was returned and use a regular expression other method to access the `PersonID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this XPath,

```
//*[@id=\"resultsDiv\"]/p[1]/a
```

selects this `a` element,

```
<a href="./t_Person.aspx?PersonID=140476">Bill%20Jones</a>
```

then this XPath,

```
substring-after(//*[@id='resultsDiv']/p[1]/a/@href, 'PersonID=')
```

will return `140476` alone, as requested.